# SSLContext not initialized in release build of Android project

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

`SSLContext not initialized in release build of Android project

I am facing an issue with SSLContext in my Android project. I have stored a .crt SSL certificate in the "src/main/res/raw" directory. The SSL certificate is working properly with the debugging build of the application. However, when I generate and use the **release **build, I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSLContext is not initialized.
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLContextImpl.engineGetSocketFactory(OpenSSLContextImpl.java:125)
> at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getSocketFactory(SSLContext.java:338)
> at app.rsn.rb.call.VishingManagerTask.doInBackground(VishingManagerTask.java:65)
> at app.rsn.rb.call.VishingManagerTask.doInBackground(VishingManagerTask.java:39)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)

I have made sure that the SSL certificate file is included in the release build's resources. I have also verified that the certificate is valid and functioning correctly in the debugging build.

Folder structure:

[image]

I am using the SSLContext to establish a secure connection with a server. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
`vishSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream certificateInputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream("res/raw/cert.crt");
            keyStore.load(null);
            if(null != certificateInputStream) {
                CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificateInputStream);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("alias", certificate);
                certificateInputStream.close();

                trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
                vishSslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);`
```

The code works perfectly in the debugging build, but fails in the release build with the "SSLContext is not initialized" exception.

I have tried different approaches, such as including the certificate file directly in the assets directory and using a different file path, but the issue persists.

What could be causing this problem? How can I resolve the "SSLContext is not initialized" exception in the release build of my Android project? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if `certificateInputStream` is null? Then you have an uninitialized SSL context.

Comment: Hello, Robert. 
Thank you for your comment; if "certificateInputStream" is null, I just put a log ("sslVishContext: input stream is null") in the else condition.

Comment: IMHO I would raise an Exception instead. It seems that your app requires this SSLContext so without it should fail.